# Getting id from keycloak

Tags: c#, .net, keycloak

I need help. I have an application where users should be able to add skills to their profiles. We use keycloak for login and I wanna use the id from the keycloak to add skills to that user. We're having some problems, so I wanted to ask if my code gets the users id correcly and if anyones have correct solution or ones better suited

`[HttpPost("skills")]
[Authorize]
public async Task AddNewSkillToUser([FromBody] SkillPostDTO skillPostDto)
{
var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
{
    return Forbid("User ID is missing or invalid.");
}

try
{
    await _userService.AddNewSkillToUserAsync(Guid.Parse(userId), skillPostDto.SkillName);
    return Ok("Skill added to user successfully.");
}
catch (UserNotFoundException ex)
{
    return NotFound(ex.Message);
}
```

}`

we get different 400 codes, think the problem is getting the id. The service method works, tested that in swagger your text